# Frame or EdgeForm disappearing out of PlotRange

Tags: graphics

I am trying to obtain a thin frame around the bars in this chart but it's proving rather tricky. Can anyone suggest a solution?

```
size = {3, 12, 8, 0.5, 7, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2};

bar[i_] := Inset[Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}],
    FaceForm@LightBlue, Rectangle[{0, -1/2}, {size[[i]], 1/2}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, size[[i]]}, {(-1/2), 1/2}}],
  {1, -(Length[size] - i + .5)}, {Left, Center}, size[[i]]];

Graphics[{LightYellow, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {15, -(Length[size] + 1)}],
  Array[bar, Length[size]]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {0, -(Length[size] + 1)}}]
```

[image]

A second version has the same problem:

```
bar[i_] := Inset[Graphics[{LightBlue,
    Rectangle[{0, -1/2}, {size[[i]], 1/2}]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, size[[i]]}, {(-1/2), 1/2}},
   Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, ImagePadding -> 0],
  {1, -(Length[size] - i + .5)}, {Left, Center}, size[[i]]];
```

**Edit**

Thanks to Heike's comment I have something I can use:

```
size = {3, 12, 8, 0.5, 7, 5, 6, 7, 3, 4, 2};

bar[i_] := Rectangle[{1, -(i - 1)}, {size[[Length[size] + 1 - i]] + 1, -i}];

Graphics[{LightYellow, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {15, -(Length[size] + 1)}],
  EdgeForm[{Thin, Black}], FaceForm@LightBlue,
  Array[bar, Length[size]]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {0, -(Length[size] + 1)}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using `Inset` to place the individual bars in the yellow rectangle instead of using `Rectangle`s directly?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot remember the solution to this problem, but I will point out that at the right ImageSize the lines are not clipped:

```
Graphics[{LightYellow, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {15, -(Length[size] + 1)}], 
  Array[bar, Length[size]]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 15}, {0, -(Length[size] + 1)}}, 
 ImageSize -> {Automatic, 450}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Okay, I think I remember the solution.  A somewhat similar problem affects BarChart, and someone solved it by creating one big polygon for all the bars and drawing Lines over it.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard - Did you work out that 450 was the right image height by trial and error? I see 150 nearly works but 650 fails more.

Comment: @Chris yes, I simply drag-resized the graphic until it looked good.  I saw that you have a working method so I didn't try to reimplement the Polygon/Line solution.